# Graph API DriveItem: How can I only get query results from the root directory (PREVENT recursive searching)?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MyDomain.sharepoint.com,00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/drive/search(q='Matrix')
```

The above correctly returns all drive files with the word "Matrix" in them within the `Shared%20Documents` directory for the site's [provided site ID](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-site-collection-web-id.html#:%7E:text=To%20Get%20Site%20Collection%20ID,site%2C%20which%20is%20a%20GUID.) (`00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444`).

However, it's recursive: it returns files with the word "Matrix" in them within subfolders too. I only want to query files in the *root* directory.

How do I `search` for file names, only within the root directory? I tried changing `/drive` to `/drive/root` like below, but it did not make a difference:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MyDomain.sharepoint.com,00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/drive/root/search(q='Matrix')
```

ChatGPT recommended adding the filter `$filter=parentReference/path eq '/drive/root'`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MySite.sharepoint.com,00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/drive/search(q='Matrix')?$filter=parentReference/path eq '/drive/root'
```

...but I got the error `"Only createdDateTime,remoteItem.shared.sharedBy.group.id,remoteItem.shared.sharedBy.user.id is supported for filtering"` which ChatGPT didn't know how to get past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by obtaining the folder `id` of the root folder and using the `/drive/items/{folderId}/children$filter` URI instead of `/drive/search`. I obtained the folder ID of the root folder by copying the `id` within the `parentReference` of an item that lies within my root directory from the output of my first command.

[image]

Then I queried the files in the root directory with the following format:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MyDomain.sharepoint.com,{siteId}/drive/items/{folderId}/children?$filter=startswith(name,'MyWord')
```

So in my case, the URI ended up looking like below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MyDomain.sharepoint.com,00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/drive/items/01NCSFADN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/children?$filter=startswith(name,'Install')
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't use the `contains` function (which functions similarly to `/search`) and had to use `startswith` because [`contains` isn't supported on `$filter` for text fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1016924/graph-api-sharepoint-list-search-contains-amp-star.html).

Finally, you can optionally tack on the end whichever field(s) you're interested in retrieving with the `select` parameter:

```
&select=name,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
```